# Is there a proper way to share a PHP entity to a ECMAScript in order to have IDE autocompletion on both sides

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, symfony

I have some string constants that are useful on the PHP (Symfony) server side as well as on the js side.

In order to factorize my code, and help js autocompleting, I'd like to have a js (react) ressource automatically generated from the php object.

example this php class:

```
class allTheStuff{
 static const thestuff1 = "STUFF1" ;
 static const thestuff2 = "STUFF2" ;
}
```

will automatically generate this js ressource :

```
const allTheStuff = {
   thestuff1 : "STUFF1" ,
   thestuff2 : "STUFF2" 
}
```

I could totally and easily code a ugly custom script to do that, but I'd like to know if there a proper way (Good practice ? webpack ? node module ? Composer vendor ? Already existing stuff ? ) as a starting point.

Comment: You could probably abuse the [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method for this.

Comment: I precise my goal is to have autocompletion on my IDE ( I often compare to these string constants, on the reactjs part, or on php to database queries )  , on the both sides,  without copy pasting the strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I assume that the values you want to share between the client and the server are constants.

Have a JSON file (example: 'constants.json') on the server side (stored on disk).

Load it to memory when you need it in the PHP code or when you get HTTP call from the client and just return the file content to the client.

Comment: Thank you , but my goal is to keep the autocompletion ability in my IDE , in PHP or JS mode . And not copy paste this constants from a file to another.

Comment: So you are looking for code generator that will get a data structure (JSON as an example) and will generate constants data structures in PHP,JS,etc. - right? webpack plugin sounds like interesting direction.